# Dynamic list break into two UL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to JS/jQuery and could use a little help understanding what I need to do.

I am populating a modal when a link is clicked. When the link is clicked a UL is being created from a data attribute. The issue I am trying to solve is that when the link is clicked it is creating just one UL and I need it to be broken into two UL's. Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/west4me/pen/BGVgPy. The link to click is "View Regions".

I believe I need to break it into two around here:

```
"</h5></div><ul class='regionList'>" +
        regionLis.join("") +
        "</ul>"
```

If you could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: what do you expect the other `<ul>` to look like?

Comment: @AndrewLohr I'm just needing to make it into two, count how many li's then break it into two UL's. The lists can get pretty long and I would like to be able to have the two UL's side by side on desktop.

Comment: So split your long list into how many shorter lists you want.

Comment: @epascarello any advice on where I should do that in the code? Should I be using .split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to split the array in half. For example

```
var firstHalf = regionLis.splice(0, Math.ceil(regionLis.length / 2));
```

This will make `firstHalf` contain the first half of the `regionLis` and the `regionLis` variable will now hold the second half.

then, the `.append()` for your modal will look like

```
.append(
  "<div class='d-block'><h5 class='text-weight-bold'>" +
    staffName +
    "</h5></div><div class='d-block'><h5 class='font-weight-light'>" +
    staffTitle +
    "</h5></div><div class='ulContainer'><ul class='regionList'>" +
    firstHalf.join("") +
    "</ul></div>" +
   "<div class='ulContainer'> <ul class='regionList'>" +
    regionLis.join("") +
    "</ul></div>"
);
```

notice the two new divs with class `ulContainer` and how the first one has `firstHalf` (the first half) and the second div has `regionLis` (the second half of the array). The two divs will need the below css to make the them align next to each other as well.

```
.ulContainer{
  display:inline;
  float:left;
}
```

Here is an [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VVBwVg) for you too

Comment: Worked like a charm. Appreciate the assist on that one. Taught me something too.